Does the Linphone SDK support viewing RTSP streams from IP cameras and transmitting them via SIP on Android?
I am developing an Android application where I need to integrate live video streams from IP cameras (using RTSP) into SIP calls and transmit stream to sip client using the Linphone SDK. I've researched the Linphone SDK documentation but couldn't find clear information on whether it natively supports this functionality.
Specific Questions:
Does the Linphone SDK provide built-in support for handling transmit RTSP streams from IP cameras on Android?
If not, what are the recommended approaches or libraries to achieve this integration?
Are there any specific configurations or settings I need to consider when setting up Linphone for this purpose?
Additional Information:
Linphone SDK version: 5.0+
Android SDK version: 33
